# Is it proper to use "stand for" while reporting data in such a case?

Tags: word-usage

is it natural or proper to use "stand for" in such a case in the sentence below.

"Looking at the CO2 produced by each type of fuel, petroleum represents the highest percentage with 42% as opposed to the natural gas which ***stands for*** the lowest with 23%."

Comment: ..natural gas which accounts for the lowest percentage of 23%. "Stand for" is an idiomatic expression which conveys different meanings:  : http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+for

Comment: forgot to ask, .. would "at"  also fit in here?  like. "..natural gas which accounts for the lowest percentage,  at 23%"

Comment: *at* looks very natural to me.  "Stands for" actually looks very odd to me here - I wouldn't say that a fuel *represents* a percentage; if anything it should be the other way around, like "this 42% represents petroleum".

Comment: This is a spoken, not written sentence, right? Lighter is better. /Looking at the CO2 produced by each type of fuel, petroleum accounts for the highest percentage at 42% versus natural gas that accounts for lowest at 23%./ Typically, we say: AT here and not of.

Comment: no, this is written information but, in either case the lighter is better :)